# Designing an Accumulating Snapshot with Repeated Groups, need advise

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse

### Situation

I need to create a pie chart that has to be able to be represented at the following levels: **District, Region, and School.**

At the student level it has to show the trend of the student over a set of periods: **"I1", "G1", "I2", "G2", "I3", "G3", "I4", "G4"**

The pie chart will show a number and pct of students with 1,2,3, or none risks factors. Risk factors being: Academics, Discipline, and Attendance. I have been given a formula to determine if a student is at risk at any of the categories above.

We have a Ralph Kimball based approach Data Warehouse.

I have a working query **at the school level** that I am able to plug the given formula through subselects and sums/counts that returns me as follows:

```
STUDENT_ID  STUDENT_NAME  PERIOD SCHOOL_YEAR  ACD_RISK  DISC_RISK  ATT_RISK   
1           Viriato       I1     2010/2011    1         1          1  

1           Viriato       G1     2010/2011    1         0          0

2           Teodosio      I1     2010/2011    0          1         0

.....................
```

The query that produces me the total number of students having 1,2,3 or 0 risk factors by doing a count sum on the output above works fine as far as performance is concerned. However when I run it at the region and district levels, performance is not acceptable.

### Solution

I need to create an **Accumulating Snapshot**

### Concerns

Ralph Kimball in **"The Complete Guide to Dimensional Modeling"** chapter 12 page 244 states on Accumulating Snapshot:

> A single row represents the complete history of something.

**Solution A: Prior to Reading Kimball**

So should I have a job that produces a table with the resultset above. But then I would have 8 rows per student per year. I would not have a single row like Kimball suggests.

**Solution B: After Reading Kimball**

```
student_id,

name, 

school_year, 

period, 

att_risk_I1, 

adm_risk_I1, 

disc_ris_I1, 

att_risk_G1, 

adm_risk_G1, 

disc_ris_G1,

.

.

.

.

att_risk_G4,

adm_risk_G4,

dis_ris_G4
```

As you can see with solution B I would have one row per student per year, and I could generate a trend graph for that student all the way from elementary school to high school with 12 rows (Grades 1st through 12th). However I am not sure I like having ATT_RISK, DISC_RISK and ADM_RISK repeated 8 times.

Which approach would you take?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what is asked here but I think your solution is simplest when you have one row per student.  That allows further aggregating later however you want to do it.

So this is a vote for b.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a performance problem, it may be worthwhile to identify the reason for it first before you move to persisting the data. One reason for this is that the base data may change and your persisted acculturation may not reflect valid data over time.
If you decide that data base data change will not change the accumulated results, then maybe this data can be generated using a batch job instead of an on-line query. This way, you will have ample window to run your query without resorting to data persistence.
Now we look at which row structure to use. I must agree with Mr. Kimball's point. However, it makes sense only if you have all the data values ready once you write the row. You don't want to visit aggregated rows to update their content as a general practice.